# How to trigger the Webpack rebuilding programmatically?

Tags: node.js, webpack

The Webpack has poor performance with [multicompiler](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/#multicompiler).
Especially, it is being caused by the watches (`watch: true`), because they are consuming much system resources and could cause the error like this:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[29700:0000022696A23110]   869488 ms: Mark-sweep 4009.8 (4138.0) -> 3997.0 (4141.2) MB, 1671.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.449, current mu = 0.024) allocation failure; scaveng
e might not succeed
[29700:0000022696A23110]   872444 ms: Mark-sweep 4013.0 (4141.2) -> 4000.1 (4144.2) MB, 2919.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.224, current mu = 0.012) allocation failure; scaveng
e might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF630979E7F node_api_throw_syntax_error+175967
 2: 00007FF630900C06 SSL_get_quiet_shutdown+65750
 3: 00007FF630901FC2 SSL_get_quiet_shutdown+70802
 4: 00007FF63139A214 v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+116
 5: 00007FF631385572 v8::Isolate::Exit+674
 6: 00007FF6312073CC v8::internal::EmbedderStackStateScope::ExplicitScopeForTesting+124
 7: 00007FF6312045EB v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+3963
 8: 00007FF63121A823 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath+2099
 9: 00007FF63121B0CD v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath+93
10: 00007FF63122A903 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+851
11: 00007FF630F1BEB5 v8::internal::DateCache::Weekday+1349
12: 00007FF6314378B1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+558193
13: 00007FF6313BAE63 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+47651
14: 00007FF5B37BB7A3

Process finished with exit code 134
```

In my case, I am using the Webpack with Gulp (however, without `webpack-steram`).
I already have the Gulp watchers for `.js` and `.ts` files and if it is possible to trigger Webpack compiler, it will be the solution.

```
const webpackCompilers: Webpack.MultiCompiler = webpack(
  [
    { entry: './index1.js', output: { filename: 'bundle1.js' } },
    { entry: './index2.js', output: { filename: 'bundle2.js' } },
  ],
  (err, stats) => {
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString() + '\n');
  }
);

gulp.watch(
  "*.ts", 
  (callback: () => void): void => {

    webpackCompilers.run((): void => {
      // ...
      callback();       
    });

  }    
};
```

Although there is the `run` method, I am not sure will will it execute the cold start (not the solution), of will rebuild incrementally (will be the solution).

### Why you are watching the files by Gulp? You should to watch everything by Webpack.

I have 3 compilers: one for the frontend (Browser runtime), for backend (NodeJS runtime) and for the Posgres data source (NodeJS runtime, but must have exposed imports). AFAIK, doing of such things by single Webpack compiler is impossible because of incompatible presets. With 3 compilers, we have 3 watchers, 3 TypeScript type checkers and 3 ES linters. Even in my high spec computer (64Gb RAM) the project building will take more than 1 minute and also rebuilding will be to slow (it will be impossible to work).

I already have delegated the linting to Gulp and implemented the caching.
Thanks to it, I have single optimized linter for all files.
But to rerun the this linting during the incremental building, the additional Gulp watcher will required.

Next thing must be done is delegating the watching to Gulp (the topic of this question) and the delegating TyepScript type checking to Gulp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although there is the `run` method, I am not sure will will it execute the cold start (not the solution), of will rebuild incrementally (will be the solution).

You can still test the [webpack.run()](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/#run).
Assuming a Webpack 5 [cache config in memory or filesystem](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/#cachetype), Webpack should remember the modules and chunks it has built, contributing to faster subsequent builds. Webpack 5's persistent caching features can further enhance incremental builds by storing cache information on the file system, allowing for incremental builds even on cold starts.

```js
module.exports = {
  // Other configuration
  cache: {
    type: 'filesystem', // Enable filesystem caching
    buildDependencies: {
      config: [__filename], // Invalidate cache when configuration changes
    },
  },
};
```

Then you can define your webpack compilers and use them in a Gulp task to watch for changes and trigger incremental builds:

```bash
Gulp Watchers --(triggers)--> Webpack Compilers
   |                                  |
   |---- Watches .ts and .js files    |---- Handles incremental builds
   |---- Triggers rebuild on change   |---- Outputs bundles
   |
   └---- Also handles linting and TypeScript type checking
```

You would use:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// Define your Webpack compilers for different targets
const webpackCompilers = webpack([
  { entry: './index1.js', output: { filename: 'bundle1.js' } },
  { entry: './index2.js', output: { filename: 'bundle2.js' } },
]);

// Gulp task to watch changes in .ts files and trigger Webpack compilation
gulp.task('watch-ts-files', () => {
  gulp.watch('*.ts', (done) => {
    webpackCompilers.run((err, stats) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Webpack compilation error:', err);
      } else {
        console.log(stats.toString({
          colors: true,
          modules: false,
          children: false,
          chunks: false,
          chunkModules: false
        }));
      }
      done(); // Signal completion of the task
    });
  });
});
```

The `webpackCompilers.run` method triggers a new compilation, and since Webpack's caching mechanisms are in place, it will only rebuild what has changed, leading to faster incremental builds.